# How to achieve floating div on scrolldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a newbie on jquery, and I want the div to hang on top of the screen when the page scrolldown is more than 50, how can I achieve this?

**I want the div to be always absolute and not fixed.**

**http://jsfiddle.net/8UCcY/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
              $(".articlebutton").css("top", "0px"); //I want this value to change dynamically as the scrollbar moves down, so that the div stays on top of screen
          } else {
              $(".articlebutton").css("top", "-50px");
          }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it to position top -100 since it is -50 and scroll occurs after 50:

```
$(".articlebutton").css("top", ($(window).scrollTop()-100)+"px");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 50) {
              $(".articlebutton").css("top", $(window).scrollTop() - 50); //I want this value to change dynamically as the scrollbar moves down, so that the div stays on top of screen
          } else {
              $(".articlebutton").css("top", $(window).scrollTop() - 100);
          }
     });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UCcY/5/)

Comment: @Abishek check the fiddle you posted, you will see.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/8UCcY/15/)**

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var top = $(".articlebutton").css('top');
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {

            $(".articlebutton").animate({
                "top": $(window).scrollTop() + "px"
            }, 400);
        } else {
            $(".articlebutton").animate({
                "top": top
            }, 400);
        }

    });
});
```

Hope this helps,thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on that line:

```
$(".articlebutton").css("top", $(window).scrollTop());
```

Or event better, use a `position: fixed; top: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply set a `position:fixed;` for the div? That way it will always be at the top anyways. See the css below

```
 .articlebutton div
 {
      position:fixed;
      top:0;
 }
```

Comment: I can't. Because the initial position is absolute. The width depends on size of the screen.

Comment: What does the width have to do with the 'top' attribute that you want to set? Also why not initialize the position to fixed as opposed to absolute? Maybe post the html?

Comment: Because the div takes its position from the main window, which is resized as % of the screen. So I can not use fixed.

Comment: I Edited the question. Fixed cannot be used. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

make the property of div as

```
div{
position : fixed;
top : 0px;
}
```

it will make you div always stay on top.. no matter how much you scroll the page

Comment: .articlebutton /*the button to see the article*/
{
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    z-index:1000;
    left: 180px;
    
     position:fixed;
    top:10px;
}
change your css to this it will work

Comment: in the question, I wrote, "no fixed div", thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is taken from https://deltafrog.com/create-floating-div-jquery/

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
if(jQuery('.right').length){

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var win_width=jQuery(window).width();
    if(win_width>1200){
        var topoffset=jQuery('.right').offset().top;
        var leftoffset=jQuery('.right').offset().left;

        var botoffset=jQuery('footer').offset().top;

        var block_height=jQuery('.floating-block').height();
        botoffset=botoffset-block_height-250;
        topoffset=topoffset-200;

        var sTop=jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        var top_fix_to_abs=botoffset-topoffset;
        if(sTop < topoffset){
            jQuery('.floating-block').removeClass('curr_fix');
            jQuery('.floating-block').removeClass('right_fix');
            jQuery('.floating-block').css('top',"");
            jQuery('.floating-block').css('left',"");
            console.log('h1');
        }
        if(sTop > topoffset && sTop<botoffset){
            jQuery('.floating-block').addClass('curr_fix');
            jQuery('.floating-block').addClass('right_fix').css('left',leftoffset);
            jQuery('.floating-block').css('top',"");
            console.log('h2');
        }
        if(sTop >=botoffset && sTop>topoffset){
            jQuery('.floating-block').removeClass('curr_fix');
            jQuery('.floating-block').css('left',0);
            jQuery('.floating-block').css('top',top_fix_to_abs);
            console.log('h3');
            //return;

        }   
    }
});
}
});
```